# Weird Issue with cor.test -- get rid of [[1]], [[2]], etc. in Results

Tags: r, function, correlation

I have the following function written to do pairwise correlation between one variable with a list of given variables.

```
myCortest <- function(dat, mainVar, varlist) {
  foo <- lapply(varlist, function(x){
    foo1 <- cor.test(get(mainVar, as.environment(dat)),
                     get(x, as.environment(dat)))
    data.frame(var1 = mainVar, var2 = x,
               R = foo1$estimate, p = foo1$p.value)
  })
  foo
}
```

It works, kinda. The results have weird [[1]], [[2]] in between like as follows:

```
myCortest(chol, "wt", c("age", "chol", "tg", "ht"))
```

```
[[1]]
    var1 var2         R            p
cor   wt  age 0.6660014 5.631448e-26

[[2]]
    var1 var2          R        p
cor   wt chol 0.06076105 0.404971

[[3]]
    var1 var2        R            p
cor   wt   tg 0.294617 3.688497e-05

[[4]]
    var1 var2         R            p
cor   wt   ht 0.8558331 2.705222e-56
```

I cannot seem to figure out what is causing the numbers in brackets to how up. I would like to get rid of them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `list` output by looping with `lapply` (`lapply` always returns a `list`).  We can `rbind` the `list` elements to a single dataset with `do.call`

```
out1 <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

where

```
out <- myCortest(chol, "wt", c("age", "chol", "tg", "ht"))
```

---

Better option is to change the funciton 'myCortest' to return the `rbind`ed output

```
myCortest <- function(dat, mainVar, varlist) {
  foo <- lapply(varlist, function(x){
    foo1 <- cor.test(get(mainVar, as.environment(dat)),
                     get(x, as.environment(dat)))
    data.frame(var1 = mainVar, var2 = x,
               R = foo1$estimate, p = foo1$p.value)
  })
  do.call(rbind, foo)
}
```

Comment: Where am I placed the out1 <- do.call(rbind, out)?

Comment: @fiverings84 the `out <- myCortest(yourdata, yourvar, varList)`

Comment: I'm not sure it is going to work. I just added a piece in the original question. I have to call the function like this: myCortest(chol, "wt", c("age", "chol", "tg", "ht")) ... can't seem to see how the do.call(rbind, out) would allow for that. Sorry ... this is a new one to me.

Comment: @fiverings84 your `out <-  myCortest(chol, "wt", c("age", "chol", "tg", "ht"))` and the output of that function is a `list`.  You can change the function to have `do.call(rbind, foo)` inside as well

Comment: @fiverings84 can you test my updated function

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I love when I learn something new.